# pandas IndexError/TypeError inconsistency with NaN values

Tags: python, exception, pandas, indexing, nan

I have several series of lists of variable length with some nulls. One example is:

```
In [108]: s0 = pd.Series([['a', 'b'],['c'],np.nan])
In [109]: s0
Out[109]: 
0    [a, b]
1       [c]
2       NaN
dtype: object
```

but another contains all `NaNs`:

```
In [110]: s1 = pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan])
In [111]: s1
Out[111]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
dtype: float64
```

I need the last item in each list, which is straightforward:

```
In [112]: s0.map(lambda x: x[-1] if isinstance(x,list) else x)
Out[112]: 
0      b
1      c
2    NaN
dtype: object
```

But whilst getting to this I discovered that, without the `isinstance`, when the indexing chokes on the `NaNs` *it does so differently on `s0` and `s1`*:

```
In [113]: s0.map(lambda x: x[-1])
...
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

In [114]: s1.map(lamda x: x[-1])
...
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Can anyone explain why? Is this a bug? I'm using Pandas 0.16.2 and Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Interesting question. It has to do with the way `pd.Series` works, as trying to replicate this with `list` and `np.array` is resulting with only the `TypeError`.

Comment: Did you try with tuples rather than lists? In my experience tuples within data frames work much better. Not sure this addresses your problem as I did not try to recreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its core, this is really a NumPy issue rather than a pandas issue.

`map` iterates over the values in the column to pass them to the `lambda` function one at a time. Underneath, columns/Series in pandas are just (slices of) NumPy arrays, so pandas defines the following [helper function](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/b60b55934dcfd789ef38dbecee62a6ecf5cddb21/pandas/src/numpy_helper.h#L92) to get the value out of the underlying array for the function. This is called by `map` on each iteration:

```C
PANDAS_INLINE PyObject*
get_value_1d(PyArrayObject* ap, Py_ssize_t i) {
  char *item = (char *) PyArray_DATA(ap) + i * PyArray_STRIDE(ap, 0);
  return PyArray_Scalar(item, PyArray_DESCR(ap), (PyObject*) ap);
}
```

The key bit is `PyArray_Scalar`, which is a NumPy API function that copies a section of a NumPy array out to return a scalar value.

The code that makes up the function is too long to post here, but [here's](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c#L625)  where to find it in the codebase. All we need to know is that the scalar it returns will match the dtype of the array it's used on.

Back to your Series: `s0` has `object` dtype while `s1` has `float64` dtype. This means that `PyArray_Scalar` will return a different type of scalar for each Series; an actual *Python* `float` object and a NumPy scalar float object respectively:

```
>>> type(s0[2])
float
>>> type(s1[0])
numpy.float64
```

The `NaN` values are returned as two different types, hence the different errors when you try to index into them using the `lambda` function.